Client or Request could be null downloading a file asynchronously from dropbox
First of all I would like to apologize but this is the first time I use these tools (HttpClient and SendAsync )
I'd like to download asynchronously a file ( video / image / text ) from dropbox by the call files/download.
This is my code but when the excecution arrive in the line with SendAsync the program exit from the function.
Is there an error? how can I find it?
 Async Function Download_Async(ByVal _file As String) As Task
     Dim client As HttpClient = New HttpClient()
     Dim _Request As HttpRequestMessage = New HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download")
     _Request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + _token)
     _Request.Headers.Add("Dropbox-API-Arg", _path_file)

     Dim _message = Await client.SendAsync(_Request)
     Dim res = Await _message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()

I installed last version of nuget package  System.Net.Http 4.3.4. and i try to change in various mode the define of HttpRequestMessage and SendAsync but this is  ( i think ) the correct way.
I changed the firsts line
   Dim client As New HttpClient
        Dim _Request = New HttpRequestMessage(Http.HttpMethod.Post, "https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download")

Error is : "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

It would be great to know what does the error message say or at least what sort of exception is thrown.

The error is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Thank you. From the stack trace could you please share with us which line is throwing this NullReferenceException?

Dim _message = Await client.SendAsync(_Request)

That means either the client or the _Request could be null. Could you please update the question with the entire stacktrace?

@PeterCsala if the code provided is accurate, neither client nor _Request is null, both are clearly shown to have values.  It looks like either there is an issue with transcribing the problem or there is a problem with something inside the request.

@Craig Yes, the provided code fragment does not indicate potential NRE. I assumed it was shared just to demonstrate the problem space, not the actual code which is thrown the exception.
